# Lifting criterion

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I am given the following result

> **Lifting criterion** : Suppose $\pi : E \to X$ is a covering map, $Y$ is a connected and locally path-connected space, and $F:Y\to X$ is a
> continuous map. Let $y\in Y$ and $e\in E$ be such that $\pi (e)=F(y)$.
> Then there exists a lift $\tilde{F}:Y\to E$ of $F$ satisfying
> $\tilde{F}(y)=e$ iff $F_*(\pi_1(Y,y))\subset \pi_*(\pi_1(E,e))$.

Now I want to show that

let $X$, $Y$ be topological spaces with universal covers $p_1$ : $\tilde{X} \to X$ and
$p_2 : \tilde{Y} \to Y$ , and $f : X \to Y$ a continuous map. Let $x \in X, \tilde{x} \in p^{-1}(x)$ and $\tilde{y} \in p^{−1}(f(x))$. Then there exists a unique continuous $\tilde{f} : \tilde{X} \to \tilde{Y}$ such that

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
\tilde{X} @>{\tilde{f}}>> \tilde{Y}\\
@Vp_1VV @VVp_2V\\
X @>{f}>> Y
\end{CD}

commutes and such that $\tilde{f}(\tilde{x}) = \tilde{y}$.

The criterion allows us to lift $f$ to a map from $X$ to $\tilde{Y}$ but then what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't even be sure that the lift of $f$ to a map from $X$ to $\tilde Y$ exists, because you have not verified that the required hypothesis of the lifting criterion holds, i.e. you have not verified that
$$f_*(\pi_1(X,x)) \subset (p_2)_*(\pi_1(\tilde Y,\tilde y))
$$
Fortunately, that's not the correct strategy for applying the lifting criterion.

Instead, you should apply the lifting criterion to the map $f \circ p_1 : \tilde X \to Y$. Now the required hypothesis does hold, because $\pi_1(\tilde X,\tilde x)$ is a trivial group, so $(f \circ p_1)_*(\pi_1(\tilde X,\tilde x))$ is the trivial subgroup of $\pi_1(Y,y)$ which is certainly contained in the subgroup $(p_2)_*(\pi_1(\tilde Y,\tilde y))$.

Comment: Thank you, I forgot that the universal cover was simply connected, so it's fundamental group is always trivial.